# Rails application throughs MySql GEM error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run the "Redmine" project management application written in Rails.
https://github.com/redmine/redmine

I downloaded it from Github and now while trying to run it (by double clicking on the rails file, I get this error in terminal:

Could not find gem 'mysql (~> 2.8.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

I have mysql 2.9.1 already installed.
I am new to the whole Rails thingy. I just installed it to be able to run this application.
So any advice on helping me run this app would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run the command `bundle install` before doing a `rails server`?

Comment: Yes I ran the bundle install. It ran successfully.

Comment: Actually after running bundle install, i was getting this error: Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
 ------ so I did "sudo gem install mysql -v '2.8.1'" and that worked fine. But again when I run the rails file, it throghs the MySql error

Answer (score 0):

could it be that it doesnt work with the latest mysql version?  make sure you stick this in your Gemfile in Rails app.

gem 'mysql', '~> 2.8.1'

also make sure its under test, or development if you want to run that locally.

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'mysql', '~> 2.8.1'
end
```

Comment: In the Gemfile, it is mentioned as gem 'mysql', '~>2.8.1'

Comment: I managed to solve it. Its working now. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest will be to tell Redmine to use your version of mysql:
Go to

\YourRedMineInstallFolder\apps\redmine\htdocs
 open the Gemfile & Gemfile.lock and change/add this line at end or in mysql area.

```
gem "mysql", "~> 2.9.1"
```

Then go to the services and restart all redmine services specially ones with "..thin" in their name(This is pretty important).